# Random WCF Exception on few user machines: The server did not provide a meaningful reply

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am getting below mentioned exception randomly on few users machines when trying to fetch data from WCF service. We have two WCF services: one is hosted locally and one is hosted on some server and we are getting this issue from both. This issue starts coming in this month only while same code is running successfully for many years.

ERROR:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

Server stack trace:

> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

Comment: Things I usually do in this situation: check the Event Viewer on the server, add logging to exceptions and log them locally, create a simple application with the same request to see if you get a different message locally.  One note on capturing and logging exceptions.  Sometimes you have to dive down deeper into the InnerException of the exception and it may be layers deep.

Comment: *issue starts coming in this month only while same code is running successfully for many years* - something has changed and you have to find out what first. Is there something common for faulty machines? E.g.  same Windows version? Then perhaps it's due to window update?

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, I don't think the error is being generated from the server.  Otherwise a FaultException would be raised and you could add a trace server log to the WCF service to get more information.  Is there a possibilty that the client and server are at different versions?  (i.e. versions of application code)